# Pass action to button

Tags: java, android, onclick, android-intent

I need to pass an Intent to `onClickListener` in Android..But in a slightly different way than normal.

I have gridView of buttons and on every first click on every button it only says which action that button does (it's for blind people) and I need the Intent started as far the user click on the same button twice in tandem.
I have this adapter

```
public class BlindAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements OnClickListener{
    private Context mContext;
    private String[] labels;
    private Button currentlyClicked;

    public BlindAdapter(Context c, String[] labels) {/*Empty*/}

    @Override
    public int getCount() {/*Empty*/}

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {/*Empty*/}

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {/*Empty*/}

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {/*Empty*/}

    private void say(String text) {/*Empty*/}

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Button btn = (Button) view;
        Log.v("id", ""+view.hashCode());
        if(this.currentlyClicked == null || this.currentlyClicked.hashCode() != view.hashCode()){
            if(this.currentlyClicked != null) this.currentlyClicked.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
            this.currentlyClicked = (Button) view;

            btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
            this.say(btn.getText().toString());
        } else{
            this.say("Zvolena volba:" + btn.getText().toString());
            btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
            this.currentlyClicked = null;
        }
    }

    //Notice I posted inly onCLick method with its body for simplicity..
```

And I instantiate it like that

```
gridview.setAdapter(
    new BlindAdapter(this.getApplicationContext(),
    new String[]{"jedna", "dva", "tri", "ctyri", "pet", "šest", "osm"})
);
```

The strings are the actions which are red to the user. So I need to pass there even the Intent for every particular button. Is possible to pass it there as another parameter?

Or is possible to somehoww override the button onclick event in my Activity and at first call the `super.OnClick` where the app decides if its first or secind click and according to the return I will stop the whole onclick event, or go on back to the overriding event in Activity and call the Intent?

Or is there better way to achieve that all? (I think that at least the first possibility I thought about is really weird).

**EDIT**

And what about make each item "focusable"..It would be much mor accessible (trackballs and so on).
Is possible to make gridViewItem only selected in first click (just take focus) and clicked only on the next click..(It's the behaviour I am trying to achieve)..

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understand the problem correctly, but since your use case is quite specific and you probably would need it again in your app, what I would do is create a custom button and use it in my layout instead of the native one.
For the string to read I would use the tag attribute rather than the text, but it makes little difference in code.

```
public class BlindButton extends Button {
    private boolean firstTime = true;
    private Intent intent;

    [...]

    public BlindButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        [...]
        setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick() {
                if (firstTime) {
                    firstTime = false;
                    say(getText());    // or getTag()
                } else {
                    if (intent != null) {
                        getContext().startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void setIntent(Intent intent) {
        this.intent = intent;
    }
    private void say(String text) {
        [...]
    }
}
```

For the intent, I think it depends what kind of action you want to trigger. I think the above setIntent could work, although I don't like it too much, but without more information I can't think of a more elegant solution.
Basically when using the BlindButton in your adapters, you wouldn't have to write any additional code (e.g. setOnClickListener or anything) but instead just call setIntent on them.

Comment: looks great..I will make it propably like that, but it does not solve my problem..I will have lot of different activities using this gridview with buttons, so I am asking how to solve the BINDING of events on buttons in particular gridviews?Propably these bindings aregoing to be done in Activity, so I need to process it through Adapter to Button. So I asked if there is a way how to override the onclick method with custom action(in Activity) which code would be ran according to the super call of the onclick handler (in Button) (yes if second click, no if first)

Comment: In that case, again sorry if I misunderstand what you mean, I think you would probably do it in the getView method that you are overriding in your adapter.

So basically when you are returning the button, or a view that contains the button (if you want more detail please post the code in your getView) you will call setIntent on it, and the custom button will take care of the rest.

Comment: So actually I need different adapter for every particular Activity?

Comment: I think this depends on how many different actions you want to be able to bind and how you decide it. Would it simply depend on the activity (i.e. each different activity would have a hardcoded list of actions you want) or is it possible to decide it dynamically based on some parameter, for example the text? I think to say more I would need to see an example of what you'd like to do in one activity.

Comment: Hey and isn't possible create own eventListener like onDoubleClickListener, which will be fired from clickListener after second click?

Comment: I guess it would be possible, but how would that help with what you want to do?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5482/discussion-between-sima-and-gianpi)

Answer (score 0):

I rethink whole think out and realized, that using GridView is bad in this case..I make it again over with using of TableLayout and defining it through XML..Then I can create own onDoubleClickListener which will be added right in Activity...That GridView I will save only for fee specific purposes, like displaying items from database, and responses from server, but not for UI at all (for standard action buttons)
Isn't it better solution?